# Google Docs: Adding "chrome://extensions/" hyperlink

Tags: validation, hyperlink, google-docs

I am trying to add a hyperlink to `chrome://extensions/` in Google Docs.

In HTML I would write:

```
<a href="chrome://extensions/">chrome://extensions/</a>
```

However, if I try to add this as a link in Google docs, I get the following validation error, and it won't let me Apply changes.

[image]

URL shorteners don't work (tried: https://goo.gl/, https://bitly.com/)

[image]

How can I add this link to Google Docs?

Note: I am having the same issue for `about:addons`

Comment: maybe you could use an url shortener service as workaround

Comment: Sadly, URL shorteners **don't** work (tried: https://bitly.com/, https://goo.gl/)